# Custom API POST JSON

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json

I created a custom API REST :

> https://domain/rest/V1/action

This is a POST request, with JSON in the body.

Example :

```
{
  "my_test_here": [
    {
      "first_field": "value1",
      "second_field": "value2",
      "and_so_on": "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my code, I try to get the JSON information but all my attempts are empty :

> $this->request1->getParams(); // with @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request1 
>    $this->request2->getParams(); // with @var \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request2

I try with `getPost()` also, but still empty...

Do you have any idea how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correct you are posting json in the body

Therefore have you tried this

`$this->getRequest()->getContent()`

Eg

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/Signifyd/Model/SignifydGateway/Response/WebhookRequest.php#L56

Comment: Use $this->request->getContent() with request = \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request. Works perfectly, thank you !